# Create an array with literal values and then explode using PySpark

Tags: arrays, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, literals

Let's say I have a dataframe like below:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([(100, 'AB', 304), (200, 'BC', 305), (300, 'CD', 306)], ['number', 'letter', 'id'])
```

I want to create an array column with `["source1", "source2", "source3"]`, which I later want to `explode`.

[image]

[image]

This did not work:

```py
df_arr = df.withColumn("source", array(lit("source1"), lit("source2"), lit("source3")))
```

I created a numpy array to use to explode which did work either. How can I explode the dataframe?

Comment: What exactly does not work? For me `df_arr.withColumn("source", F.explode("source")).show()` prints the expected result.

Comment: creating an array does not work

Comment: can you try to change your import to `from pyspark.sql import functions as F` and then use `F.array`?

Comment: do you get any exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

worked as per werner suggestion

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
df2=df.withColumn("source", F.array(lit("source1"),lit("source2"),lit("source3")))
df2.withColumn("source", F.explode("source")).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

From **Spark 3.4+** you can use lists *inside* `lit`:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(100, 'AB', 304), (200, 'BC', 305), (300, 'CD', 306)],
    ['number', 'letter', 'id']
)
df = df.withColumn('source', F.explode(F.lit(['source1', 'source2', 'source3'])))

df.show()
# +------+------+---+-------+
# |number|letter| id| source|
# +------+------+---+-------+
# |   100|    AB|304|source1|
# |   100|    AB|304|source2|
# |   100|    AB|304|source3|
# |   200|    BC|305|source1|
# |   200|    BC|305|source2|
# |   200|    BC|305|source3|
# |   300|    CD|306|source1|
# |   300|    CD|306|source2|
# |   300|    CD|306|source3|
# +------+------+---+-------+
```

Another way - use Python list when creating the dataframe and later `explode`:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

sources = ['source1', 'source2', 'source3']
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(100, 'AB', 304, sources),
     (200, 'BC', 305, sources),
     (300, 'CD', 306, sources)],
    ['number', 'letter', 'id', 'source'])
df = df.withColumn('source', F.explode('source'))

df.show()
# +------+------+---+-------+
# |number|letter| id| source|
# +------+------+---+-------+
# |   100|    AB|304|source1|
# |   100|    AB|304|source2|
# |   100|    AB|304|source3|
# |   200|    BC|305|source1|
# |   200|    BC|305|source2|
# |   200|    BC|305|source3|
# |   300|    CD|306|source1|
# |   300|    CD|306|source2|
# |   300|    CD|306|source3|
# +------+------+---+-------+
```